# How to remove the blue header loading indicator in Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter

check this image, how to remove a blue indicator from a header from flutter web

[image]

Comment: This indicator is a debug mode only functionality, it will not be displayed on a release build.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

it's only display on debug mode. first you release build you can't show this indicator

Answer (score 1):

It's only active only on debug mode or profile mode Please try with release mode and you'll see no blue header indicator